# MVC 4 DataAnnotations on Nullable<int>

Tags: regex, model-view-controller, nullable

I am trying to use the following on a MVC Model class and not getting the expected error when entering letters. I want this field to only accept numbers.

```
[RegularExpression("[0-9]*", ErrorMessage = "Must be integer.")]
public Nullable<int> Runtime { get; set; }
```

Oddly to me, the error only displays when entering a combination of letters and numbers. (i.e. FFF5758)

Can someone please help me understand what is wrong?

Many thanks!

Controller:

```
    //
    // GET: /Movies/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.RatingId = new SelectList(db.Ratings, "RatingId", "Rating");
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Movies/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Movies movies)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Movies.Add(movies);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.RatingId = new SelectList(db.Ratings, "RatingId", "Rating", movies.RatingId);
        return View(movies);
    }
```

View:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Runtime)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Runtime)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Runtime)
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry,,, code did not paste as expected. Should be: public Nullable<int> Runtime { get; set; }

Comment: You can edit your own post. Just click the edit button beneath it and change what you want.

Comment: New to sight... thanks for the tip, Ryan

Comment: Paste your controller and view code too. Wiring of the error message depends on how you've set them up.

Comment: Controller and ViewModel look fine. What about the view? Are other errors being displayed?

Comment: See the difference in my code below in how nullable int is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
    [RegularExpression(@"[0-9]*", ErrorMessage = "Must be integer.")]
    [Range(typeof(int), "30", "300", ErrorMessage = "Must be a sensible integer value.")]
    public int? Runtime { get; set; }
```

This also means the runtime cannot be over a billion minutes.

Comment: Tried this. I receive the expected error message only when entering numbers. I can enter anything else without any message. Very unexpected.

Comment: How about this? Borrowed the RegularExpression annotation from your code.

Comment: Same scenario. I receive the message when entering numbers: getting Must be a sensible integer value. Not finding a ton of sites dedicated to this dilemma, so I appreciate your help.

Comment: Change the EditorFor to TextBoxFor in the view. And do a view source to see if that is any different. It should be but I don't know if that makes the difference.

Comment: Freakin' genius, Mukus!!! Worked splendidly! Not sure why TextBoxFor works over EditorFor (guess I'll be researching that), but extremely happy this works now. Thank you!

Comment: Do a view source to see how differently those two render. I can't remember.